# Push Notification Amazon

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, push-notification

I have a problem with aws .
I do all step from https://console.aws.amazon.com/mobilehub/home?region=us-east-1#/75a98ed6-3ba6-4974-a3b2-4ba9c53a9b8f/source?platform=ios-swift&topic=u101

but when I build my project I get many error .

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSContentManager.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSS3ListObjectsOutput", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSContentManager.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSContentManager.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSS3", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSContentManager.o)
```

I use of cocoapod for other lib . but for aws I add sdk to my project .

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'MovieLand' do
use_frameworks!
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'Starscream'
pod 'RealmSwift'
pod 'SnapKit', '~> 3.0.2'
pod 'Kingfisher'
pod 'TZStackView'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
pod 'FontBlaster'
pod 'IDMPhotoBrowser'
pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift'
pod 'UIColor_Hex_Swift'
pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 4.0'
pod 'ObjectMapper', '~> 2.2'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', git: 'https://github.com/BaiduHiDeviOS/SwiftyJSON.git', branch: 'swift3'
end
```

this is my Podfile.

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem . I have to add things in podfile

```
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.13.1'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.13.1'
pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 4.0.0'
pod 'AWSSNS', '~>2.5.0'
pod 'AWSS3', '~>2.5.0'
pod 'AWSLambda', '~>2.5.0'
pod 'AWSCognito', '~>2.5.0'
pod 'AWSCognitoIdentityProvider', '~>2.5.0'
```

this is not in doc's amazon